# Load react component upon server response

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React and I am sending a POST request to the server with let's say Component A and upon request I want to redirect to another Component B with passing some data in props. Is it possible to accomplish this from the client-side or should I use server side rendering? I want to call Component B here:

```
   axios
        .post('http://localhost:3000/finish-registration', {
            newUserInfo: jsonData,
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log();
            if (response.status.toString() === '200') {
                // I want to LOAD COMPONENT B HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                return (
                    <Switch>
                        <Redirect
                            from="/finish-registration"
                            to="/dashboard"
                            component={(props: { role: userInfo.role }) => <Dashboard {...props} />}
                        />
                    </Switch>
                );
            }
            return new Error('Error receiving server response');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 You must set a flag in state

 Example :

   axios
        .post('http://localhost:3000/finish-registration', {
            newUserInfo: jsonData,
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log();
            if (response.status.toString() === '200') {
                // I want to LOAD COMPONENT B HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                setState({someflag: 1 or true})
            }
            return new Error('Error receiving server response');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });


       In render function give condition - 

       render() {
       if(this.state.someflag) {
        // this will render only when response comes.
        <ComponentB/>
       } 
       other render code must be here...
       }

  NOTE: Always call api in **componentDidMount()**.
```

Comment: Have been considering this option, but thought there is a better option. Will stick to this one if there won't be any better solution. Thanks!